# SYSUTCDATETIME() return same result in a transaction, when executed multiple times within 2 milliseconds

Tags: sql-server

ISSUE: SYSUTCDATETIME()  return same result in a transaction, when executed multiple times within 2 milliseconds.

In my table I am using DATETIME2 column as a key column. And I am using SYSUTCDATETIME() function to generate the timestamp in my insert statement.

I am facing duplicate key issue when I am trying to insert multiple records in a SINGLE transaction within a millisecond.

ERROR : Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AUT_FNCTN' with unique index 'XAF01'. The duplicate key value is (6030, EC_ACCESS_OVERRIDE, 0001-01-01, 2019-11-11 08:50:58.5005720, C).

I worked around the issue by adding delay of 2ms between statements, to get different value from SYSUTCDATETIME();

EXPECTATION

But the above work-around IS NOT a practical solution for my application, and application is expecting more accurate and different value from SYSUTCDATETIME() in each statement execution within a SINGLE transaction.

Steps to replicate:

---

Below are the three scenarios to replicate the issue, where

Scenario 1 -  Actual application scenario (PROBLEMATIC)

Scenario 3 -  work-around scenario - NOT ACCEPTED by application team, as adding delay leads to application performance.

--Scenario 1:

---

```
begin transaction

go

begin

select sysutcdatetime();

select sysutcdatetime();

end;



--Result

--------------------------

2019-11-11 08:52:58.8196155

2019-11-11 08:52:58.8196155  --Expecting different value by application.
```

--Scenario 2:(Issue is not solved by adding delay of 1 millisecond)

---

```
begin transaction

go

begin

select sysutcdatetime();

waitfor delay '00:00:00.001' select sysutcdatetime();

end;



--Result

--------------------------

2019-11-11 08:54:16.7611866

2019-11-11 08:54:16.7611866
```

--Scenario 3: (Worked around by adding delay of 2 milliseconds)

```
-------------



begin transaction

go

begin

select sysutcdatetime();

waitfor delay '00:00:00.002' select sysutcdatetime();

end;



--Result

--------------------------

2019-11-11 08:54:39.2441079

2019-11-11 08:54:39.2597361
```

Comment: We can't fix your expectations. [`SYSUTCDATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "SQL Server obtains the date and time values by using the GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() Windows API. *The accuracy depends on the computer hardware and version of Windows on which the instance of SQL Server is running.*". It's job is *not* to return unique values, it's to provide you the time.

Comment: i think it got to do with `SQL Server` rounding the value to 0, 3, 7 milliseconds, so you value `00:00:00.001` gets rounded to `00:00:00.000`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Squirrel - `SYSUTCDATETIME` returns a `datetime2`, a data type designed to avoid the limitation of the past embedded in `datetime`.

Comment: I am referring to the `waitfor delay`. The value expected is `datetime`

Comment: use transaction, try this `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;`

Comment: why aren't you using `identity` as primary key ? or create a `composite primary key` with `identity` + `datetime2`

Comment: Depending on your queries and data, it can be a good idea to make a date/time column the (non-unique) clustered index, but you should never use it as a key unless you can really guarantee a monotonically increasing clock with sufficient precision (which `SYSUTCDATETIME` does not, as you've found out -- even if the underlying software and hardware work together perfectly, the way the optimizer evaluates expressions can still easily yield "duplicates"). Even then it's iffy once you start adding parallel processing -- if you think getting one accurate clock is hard, try multiple.